# Strange setTimeout behaviour Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, settimeout

The following script is supposed to do the following:

At page load, it will set a timeout of 20 seconds, then the desired content will be updated in an ajax call automatically.
If the user clicks a button that says RELOAD, it will call to function `reloadContent()` and thus clearing the timeout and setting one again.

So basically, it will should restart the timeout if the user manually reloaded, to avoid too close calls.

It works half, because the timer seems to be reset, but the `reloadContentTimeout()` will execute after 10 seconds of the manually loaded action, which is half the timeout time.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

```
  /**
   *  Reload content
   */
  function reloadContent(elementId) {
    $(elementId).load(window.location.href+' '+elementId+' > *');
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    reloadContentTimeout(false);
  }

  /**
   * Reload content every X seconds (20)
   */
  var timeoutId;
  function reloadContentTimeout(now)
  {
    now = (typeof now === 'undefined' ? true : now);
    if( now ) {
      reloadContent('#table-content');
    }
    timeoutId = setTimeout(reloadContentTimeout, 1000 * 20);
  }
  reloadContentTimeout(false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you call `reloadContentTimeout` twice, which reassigns `timeoutId`.  One of those IDs does not get cleared and the event fires more often than it should.  Let's unfold your call stack a bit:

```
if (now) {
    $(elementId).load();
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    // this reassigns timeoutId
    reloadContentTimeout(false)
}
// this is where timeoutId is assigned.  It gets assigned
// by this call, but also the call above.
timeoutId = setTimeout(reloadContentTimeout, 1000 * 20);
```

I'll cut to the chase: this will solve the problem.

```
if (now) {
    /* snip */
}
else {
    timeoutId = /* snip */
}
```

Comment: Indeed, I've done console.log and saw it was creating 2 timeouts, and clearing only the last. Putting the `else` solved it. Thansk!

Answer (score 1):

Please check the order of your calls

- Every call to reloadContentTimeout with start a new timeout (for both possible parameter values "undefined" and "false")
- After 20 seconds you reload the content, which will start a new timeout after clearing the old one (which is quite useless, because the timer already fired). And then you start another timeout and reassign timeoutId without clearing the one you created before. Now you have two timeouts running, which will continuously happen after every timeout finished

Check the answer from @Explosion Pills. It will help you solve the problem

Comment: Thanks, clearing the timeout has an effect if the reloadContent was triggered manually (by pressing the button Reload).